# Using variable in object method results in "Unknown Format"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, colors, react-select

When I'm trying to use the provided example at this page[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-zxqg0), react simply returns with "Unknown Format" at the first line using `const color = chroma(data.color);`

```
import chroma from "chroma-js";

const runeColorStyles = {
  control: styles => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
  option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color); // First error is here
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: isDisabled
        ? null
        : isSelected
        ? data.color
        : isFocused
        ? color.alpha(0.1).css()
        : null,
      color: isDisabled
        ? '#ccc'
        : isSelected
        ? chroma.contrast(color, 'white') > 2
          ? 'white'
          : 'black'
        : data.color,
      cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',

      ':active': {
        ...styles[':active'],
        backgroundColor: !isDisabled && (isSelected ? data.color : color.alpha(0.3).css()),
      },
    };
  },
  multiValue: (styles, { data }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: color.alpha(0.1).css(),
    };
  },
  multiValueLabel: (styles, { data }) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: data.color,
  }),
  multiValueRemove: (styles, { data }) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: data.color,
    ':hover': {
      backgroundColor: data.color,
      color: 'white',
    },
  }),
};
```

I've got no clue why this is happening on my side. It's  very weird because it works perfectly fine in their example page.

Comment: Just wondering if you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This one occurred to me when using CreatableSelect and was trying to type a new option. I used `const color = chroma(data.color ?? 'black');` to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

```
 const color = chroma(data.color);
```

The first step is to get your color into chroma.js. That's what the generic constructor chroma() does. This function attempts to guess the format of the input color for you. so the data.color requires a valid color.

```
 colourStyles = {
    control: styles => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
    option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
      const color = chroma(data.color);
      return {
        ......
      };
    }
```

colourOption object which you pass to the options will be available as the data  - **option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected })**. if the color is not present in the colourOption object it will through an error *“Unknown Format”*.

```
<Select className="basic-single" classNamePrefix="select" defaultValue={colourOptions[0]}
isDisabled={isDisabled} isLoading={isLoading} isClearable={isClearable}
isRtl={isRtl} isSearchable={isSearchable} name="color" 
options={colourOptions} <!-- colourOptions object -->
styles={colourStyles} />
```

**colourOptions object :**

```
   colourOptions:[
        { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
        { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
        { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
        { value: 'red', label: 'Red', color: '#FF5630', isFixed: true },
        { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange', color: '#FF8B00' },
        { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow', color: '#FFC400' },
        { value: 'green', label: 'Green', color: '#36B37E' },
        { value: 'forest', label: 'Forest', color: '#00875A' },
        { value: 'slate', label: 'Slate', color: '#253858' },
        { value: 'silver', label: 'Silver', color: '#666666' },
      ]
```

***Note***: Make sure that the **color** property exists in colourOptions.

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-zxqg0